# My old domain is not 301 redirecting to new domain after 15 days of Migration?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, http-status-code-301

15 day ago, I migrated my WordPress site from old domain to new domain. 
And I migrated successfully.

I added these line of code for the redirection:  -

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks

 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

everything was working fine but after 15 days when I type in old URL in Google then It shows me error 22.

[Click here to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1zQD.jpg)

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask, which site did you put the rewrite rule on?

Comment: my new URL: http://beginnersblog.org. it is working well but the problem is with my old domain

Comment: Well the error comes from Incapsula, and links to https://www.incapsula.com/why-am-i-seeing-this-page.html?src=23&utm_source=blockingpages for explanation of the issue. That service seems not able any more to properly resolve the host name. But we’d need to know more details about what kind of setup you have there to say any more.

Comment: hey, I did everything. I mean I put the code in the  .htaccess file and tell the google about 301 redirections and a full process followed by https://themeisle.com/blog/move-wordpress-to-a-new-domain/ guide

Answer (score -1):

The redirects would need to be in a .htaccess file in the root directory of the server where your old domain resides.

Here is a really good guide on the basics of 301 Redirects.

If you need any help, please drop me a message.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/301-redirects/

Cheers,
Jake